# Why isn't four children inside parent fitting?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently making a `footer`for my website and met a very unanticipated result. So, I have this `footer` with *four* different menus inside them, acting as the children of the `footer`. The menus are each set to `width: 25%;` and `display: inline-block;`, it should fit perfectly, shouldn't it as 100% divided by 4 is 25%? However, the last menu breaks out of the `footer`.

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gdjwmm9u/) of what I'm getting.

As you can see in the example, the *journal menu* is breaking out of the grid, but the menus are each set to `width: 25%;` and `display: inline-block;`.

What could possibly be the problem here and how can I solve it without revising my `width` of each menu?

I'm more than happy to provide anything to clarify my question if this was not enough.

Here's the relevant code as well.

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="peasant">Explore</h6>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Philosophy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="peasant">Services</h6>
                    <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="peasant">Contact</h6>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="peasant">Journal</h6>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer.footer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.menu {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.footer .menu ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any clarification of what's happening here would be appreciated as well!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: In Russian: [Как прижать блоки друг к другу?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468547/178988)

Comment: I'm not fluent in Russian, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply `display: inline-flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to the `.menu-wrapper`.

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

inline-block element takes some extra space(like 4px). to get rid of this bug you have 2 options. 
either add `margin-right: -0.25em` for the inline-block element, in your case `.menu`

or

you can reset font-size and line-height at parent. in this case,

```
.menu-wrapper {
    font-size:0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

and use the actual font-size and line-height in the child

```
.menu {
    font-size: "your font size";
    line-height: "your line height";
}
```

this will work

Comment: That's a hack. And it depends on font.

Comment: @Qwertiy yes, ofcourse it's a hack. for inline-block we have this hack. we also have other hacks like removing white-spaces from markup itself but it's little hard-code so this hack looks better. and about the font, if the font have problem, you can simply use the margin hack as i mentioned above.

Comment: Removing spaces is not a hack.

Comment: well, it's hard-code when you have to change the markup itself. i would prefer using float or flex property to achieve it without hack.

Comment: Yep, flex seems to be better.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a space between them.
The only non-hack way to fix it keeping `inline-block`s is to remove spaces in markup.
The other ways are to use flex or float.
Everything else (like margin or font-size) is hacks.

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  margin: .5em 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background: silver;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>
    1
  </div><div>
    2
  </div><div>
    3
  </div><div>
    4
  </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div>1</div><!--
--><div>2</div><!--
--><div>3</div><!--
--><div>4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this some kind of white-space issue?

Answer (score 1):

No need to write that much CSS just use three line and here is your solution.

```css
.menu-wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
          <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                  <h6 class="peasant">Explore</h6>
                  <li><a href="#">Our Philosophy</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                  <h6 class="peasant">Services</h6>
                  <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                  <h6 class="peasant">Contact</h6>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                  <h6 class="peasant">Journal</h6>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Content breaks out of the grid because there are tab characters between the menus:

[image]

These are considered as space by HTML, and add to the overall width.

Some ways to solve this are:

- Minimize the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/9cmLaqhp/1/
- Add `float:left;` into `.menu`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution could be this .take a look,
If you wanna see the demo here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/nazarbecks/pen/jVRwyw?editors=1100)

```
.footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.menu-wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}
.footer .menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footer .menu ul  li {
    list-style: none;
}
```